# Why does the North Wind database not appear in SSMS after running the script?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, northwind

I copied (copy & past) the script from
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs/instnwnd%20(Azure%20SQL%20Database).sql

to SSMS, ran it, and refreshed the database but the north wind still does not appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj4TM.png)

Comment: The script begins with `-- This script does not create a database`, that might be a clue

Comment: Why NorthWind? That is a very old sample database designed for sql server 2000 (i believe). Why not use the current sample [WorldWide Importers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/wide-world-importers-oltp-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16) and just restore the backup?

Comment: Yes. that was it. Thank you HoneyBadger!

Comment: and here is the relevant script: https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs/instnwnd.sql

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get the correct result:

1. From Object Explorer right click on "Databases" and select "New Database"
2. Database Name:  enter "Northwind" then press OK
3. Disconnect and Reconnect Object Explorer with the icons that look like electric plugs -> Northwind DB will be there
4. From web browser go to
   https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs and select "instnwnd.sql (currently the second choice)
5. Select instnwnd.sql, download or click the "RAW" button.

6a. RAW:  script is onscreen so you can CTRL+A to select the entire script then CTRL+C to copy to load the script to the clipboard.
6b. Downloaded:  Open the instnwnd.sql in a text editor and press CTRL+A to select the entire script then CTRL+C to copy to load the script to the clipboard.

7. With the script loaded in the clipboard, go back to SQL and right-click on "Northwind" and select "New Query"
8. In the New Query window, enter CTRL+V to paste the whole script.
9. From the SQL ribbon select the Execute button.

That's it.  Worked for me.

[Screen Captures][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J3Wa.png

Answer (score 0):

The tables are loaded into your current database which you have already created. check in them. If you don't have any database created check in

Databases > System Databases > Master > Tables.